# Simple Calculus question (Substitution)

Tags: calculus

My question is "To show 
$ \int_{1}^\alpha {1\over1+x^2} dx = \int_{1\over\alpha}^1 {1\over 1+u^2} du$

such that 
$u = \frac{1}{x}$ and $\alpha $ > 1,

I got to

$ \int_{1}^\alpha {1\over1+x^2} dx = -\int_{1}^{1\over\alpha} {1\over 1+{1\over u}^2} {du\over u^2}  $

but i don't know how to swap the upper bound and lower bound around, could someone please explain it clearly to me?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution to the original problem that doesn't use substitution.

Define $\displaystyle f(\alpha) = \int_1^\alpha \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}dx$, and $\displaystyle g(\alpha)=\int_{1/\alpha}^1\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}dx$.

Note that $f(1)=g(1)=0$.  By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $$f'(\alpha)=\dfrac{1}{1+\alpha^2}.$$

By the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule,  $$g'(\alpha)=\dfrac{-1}{1+(1/\alpha)^2}\cdot\dfrac{-1}{\alpha^2}=\dfrac{1}{1+\alpha^2}.$$

Because $f(1)=g(1)$ and $f'=g'$, it follows from the mean value theorem that $f=g$.

Comment: @AWertheim: Thanks. Your answer is nice and more helpful for answering the actual question.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, though I haven't learn about the mean value theorem yet. I got this question from one of my past papers, and it asked me to use substitution instead.

Comment: @Moses:  You're welcome.  Here's a further explanation of what's going on here.  If you consider the function $h(\alpha)=f(\alpha)-g(\alpha)$, then the above shows that $h(1)=0$, and $h'(\alpha)\equiv 0$.  If a function has derivative always equal to $0$, then it is a constant function, and therefore $h(\alpha)\equiv 0$, which means $f(\alpha)\equiv g(\alpha)$.  The mean value theorem makes rigorous the intuitively plausible fact that a function with zero derivative must be constant.  If two racers start in the same location and go at the same rate, then they are always in the same location.

Answer (score 1):

It follows from the elementary property of integrals that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = -\int_{b}^{a} f(x)dx$, and the convention that integrals are typically written $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ where $a \leq b$. Since $\alpha > 1, \frac{1}{\alpha} < 1$.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, now I understand how to swap the upper and lower bound around.